# Why sometimes kendo UI Grid can not show the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

My problem is: when I change db.Contacts.Where( x => x.Id > 100).Select(...), The KendoUI Grid cannot show the data. However, when x=>x.Id < 100, it can show the data.
If I delete the Where(...), it also can not show the data.

What is the wrong? Thank you very much.

Here is my code.

```
    public class HelloOneController : Controller
    {
           ......
        public JsonResult Contacts_Read()
        {
            var query = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.Id < 100 )
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Email = x.Email,
                    FirstName = x.FirstName,
                    LastName = x.LastName

                }).ToList();
            }

            return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
             ......
    }


$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: "/HelloOne/Contacts_Read",
            dataType: "json"
        },
        schema: {
            model:{
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number" },
                    Email: { type: "string" },
                    FirstName: { type: "string" },
                    LastName: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20
    },
    height: 500,
    groupable: false,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },

    columns: [
        { title: "Id", field: "Id", width: 50 },
        { title: "Email", field: "Email" },
        { title: "First Name", field: "FirstName" },
        { title: "Last Name", field: "LastName" }
    ]

});
```

Comment: please check your database. Is there any row which ID >100 at first and also response for datasource.

Comment: How many items are there with Id > 100? Maybe that is the cause...

Comment: I think there are not many items, perhaps 103946 items ,The Chrome shows 500 internal server error. Thank you for your reply.